# Cannot deploy app to emulator in Android Studio - "unknown avd"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager

I made a simple hello world app which I would like to deploy to an emulator in Android Studio.

This used to work before for exactly the same project (I installed all necessary packages) but this time for some random reason, in the run options when I select "Target: Emulator", under the "prefer Android virtual device" I get the following in red: "Unknown AVD".

I've googled around and the answers vary. The answer that seems to make the most sense is:

> You have to install all Intel Image Library and Google API for your
>   desired API. Go to your SDK Manager and check intel system images is
>   installed or not if not then you have to installed it as well install
>   Google API Library.

However I don't have these "Intel Image libraries" and "Google API" options in SDK manager. Are these shorthand aliases for other names in the options?

Any ideas on how to get the emulator up and running?

A bit of information on my environment:

- Android Studio 2.3.3
- Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit
- Gradle Version: 3.3
- Selected SDK Platform Package: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat)/ API Level 25
  Revision 3
- Virtual Device: Nexus 5X API 25

Comment: just run it on a real device (tried it a while ago and debugging is fantastic, adb run android or something)

Comment: The question is around getting an emulator running, not a device

Comment: Any other takers?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Christoforos I ended up doing it on a another computer with new installation

Answer (score 2):

Try to kill the adb server and restart it.

Locate your adb binary (linux/osx) or adb.exe (windows) and do:

adb kill-server

adb start-server

this should fix your problem

Even if your problem still not solved then Restart emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the `adb.exe` by going to where your sdk is installed and go into platform-tools. Mine is the default and also the most common (**`C:/User/$USER$/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platform-tools/`**) 
After that **kill the server** and start the server back up. That might fix it, if not drop a comment and let someone know that the problem isn't yet resolved someone may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks i managed to find the exe. Killed it and restarted it but still not resolved. Infact I got a message that the server wasnt even running so there was nothing to kill

Answer (score 0):

this problem may be related to the version of the gradle file of your application. Try this:

goto Android -> Gradle Scripts -> Build Gradle(Module :app)